# How to generate random values across many requests

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I want to generate some random numbers for many Servlet requests.
The problem is if i use a new Random object in each servlet, the overall probability will be incorrect.

E.g. with around 10000+ reqeusts, i expect all random value should be evenly distributed within the range.

Comment: In what sense will the overall probability be incorrect?
Anyhow, if you want a single Random object, just put in one class and make it static.

Answer (score 2):

So why not use a global `Random` instance?

Or you can use `ThreadLocalRandom` which is faster. And it is kind of global because you cannot really create an instance of it. You can get an instance by calling `ThreadLocalRandom.current()`. In Java 7, it returns a per-thread instance. In Java 8, it is further optimized, it'll always return the same singleton.

Comment: I am new to GAE and servlet. Not sure if each servlet requests are treated like a standalone application and handled individually by different threads on the cloud server. Will try your suggestion when I back home. thx

Comment: @Nick Your servlet classes are instanciated once by the JVM when an App instance spins up (resp. on the first request). Then, your code is called by a unique Thread, one request after the other. Using a singleton is a good idea, you will have consistency across requests on a given instance. If you add the threadsafe=true element in your config file, you will get your code called by many threads, allowing concurrency on a single instance (meaning the requests will be treated paralelly).

Answer (score 0):

It is a little bit complicated to get really random sequence using Random. Random is LCG-based with 2^48 period and you need to be very careful with seed. There is a way to generate single sequence using DataStore to keep your current value, but performance will be not very good because you will need to update value every time you generate new random number. It means that you will be able too reach 10-20 request/sec without memcahce and probably around 100 req/sec with memcache. Sharding will not be very helpful because you need to keep atomic seed value.

Algorithm will looks like:

1. Generate first Integer (to use long you will need additional processing. It is much simpler to generate int).
2. set seed = random <<< 16
3. Save seed to DataStore (do not forget about transaction)
4. On every next request (whole op should be in a single transcation):

   4.1. Read seed from DataStore

   4.2. Create new Random with your seed.

   4.3. Generate new int.

   4.4. Set seed = random <<< 16

   4.5. Save seed to DataStore