# About the principle of Java SecureRandom class

Tags: java, servlets, random

My goal is to generate a "cryptographically strong random number" each time I want one, across different requests from different clients using servlet. The java.security.SecureRandom class will do. I got some question about its "randomness" or "unpredicability" and how to use it correctly.

According to the javadoc, the seed is chosen by the implementation itself, and it will use some "true randomness" from the hardware to achieve its goal.

Should I keep the generated value each time like a normal pseudo number generator or can I create an instance of SecureRandom class each time I want a cryptographically strong random number (since the seed itself is "truly random" maybe? )?

If I have to keep the generated value each time and generate the next value according to the previous one, I'll have to use a singleton random object in my single/cluster server, which will degerade the performance maybe.

But will the second method work? My platform is windows. In javadoc, it doesn't say whether truly in windows the hardware randomness is utilized. What on earth is the randomness achieved , can I new a SecureRandom each time and guaranteed the true randomness and unpredicability?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14949683/how-to-generate-random-values-across-many-requests, particularly [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14949683/how-to-generate-random-values-across-many-requests#comment20987263_14949734).

Comment: Thanks, but my question is not how to achieve singleton in servlet but whether I should use a singleton. I'm interested in the principle of SecureRandom and want to know if I don't use a singleton, will I get the same "randomness" from SecureRandom or to say, is the randomness of SecureRandom dependent from the last value it generated ??

Comment: @waytofall it's hard to say because it's going to be dependent on the underlying implementation.  FWIW, java.util.UUID.randomUUID() which is asserted to be cryptographically strong, uses a single static instance.  I don't think you need to chain values either.

Comment: @Taylor Thanks, the java.util.UUID.randomUUID() should work. But if I use SecureRandom, do you mean that I can instantiate a new object each time I want one true random number ??

Comment: @waytofall You can, but that will be slower.  You can keep a single instance per jvm, and you don't have to worry about sequential value retrieval.